# I want to sort this list in alphabetical order by company name

Tags: ubuntu, sort

so i have a file called `test.txt` that contain the following lines.

```
 1.The Home Depot (Ranked 28): home improvement; Atlanta, GA.
 2.United Parcel Service (Ranked 48): shipping; Atlanta, GA.
 3.The Coca-Cola Company (Ranked 62): soft drinks; Atlanta, GA. 
 4.Delta Air Lines, Inc. (Ranked 68): airline; Atlanta, GA.
 5.Aflac, Incorporated (Ranked 135): insurance; Columbus, GA. 
 6.The Southern Company (Ranked 162): energy; Atlanta, GA.
 7.Genuine Parts Company (Ranked 183): replacement parts; Atlanta, GA. 
 8.First Data Corporation (Ranked 249): payment processing;Atlanta,GA. 
 9.WestRock (Ranked 251): corrugated and consumer Norcross, GA
10.HD Supply Holdings, Inc. (Ranked 320): industrial , Atlanta GA  
11.Suntrust Banks, Inc. (Ranked 329): banking; Atlanta, GA.
12.Mohawk Industries, Inc. (Ranked 338): flooring manufacturer; Calhoun, GA.
```

The command I used was `sed 's/[0-9]*[.]//' test.txt | awk -F"(" '{print NF,$1}' | sort` which gave the company names only in alphabetical order.

```
Aflac, Incorporated
Delta Air Lines
Genuine Parts Company 
First Data Corporation
HD Supply Holdings
Mohawk Industries
Suntrust Banks
The Coca-Cola Company
The Home Depot
The Southern Company
```

However I want the whole line to be displayed as well, not just the company names.

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: ... better: post the command you tried, the actual result *and* the expected result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Take 2) Assuming the file contents are:

```
  1.The Home Depot (Ranked 28): home improvement; Atlanta, GA.
  2.United Parcel Service (Ranked 48): shipping; Atlanta, GA.
  3.The Coca-Cola Company (Ranked 62): soft drinks; Atlanta, GA. 
  4.Delta Air Lines, Inc. (Ranked 68): airline; Atlanta, GA.
```

Since the data you want to sort on appears after a dot, you could explicitly set the dot as a separator with `-t .` and then sort on the second field:

```
$ sort -t. -k2 test.txt
  4.Delta Air Lines, Inc. (Ranked 68): airline; Atlanta, GA.
  3.The Coca-Cola Company (Ranked 62): soft drinks; Atlanta, GA. 
  1.The Home Depot (Ranked 28): home improvement; Atlanta, GA.
  2.United Parcel Service (Ranked 48): shipping; Atlanta, GA.
```

<sub>(There's some leading whitespace shown in the question. I just copied it exactly here, but it doesn't matter for the sort if that's really there or not.)</sub>

Comment: yea i tried that, doesnt seem to be working

Comment: Probably spaces as separator, missing -t " "

Comment: Whitespace is the default field separator for `sort`.

Comment: You've a space separating the `1.` from the `Apple school`. The original file doesn't.

Comment: The _original_ original file did.

Comment: @roaima, yep, originally the Q had the space there (actually it had _two_ on the first line, but I thought that an error)

Comment: So it does. I hate it when important things like that get changed without explanation

Comment: sorry i'll repost with the original file. and the other recommendations thanks

Comment: @Rashad, well, I for one can't really see any use for reposting the original question. If the question as it stands now is how you meant it, that should be fine. Just make sure to post the exact data _the next time_.

Comment: if i were to do this without k would it be sort +0 -2